# How can I search MagicCards.info for an exact color identity match?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

My friends and I are experimenting with various potential Commander decks at the moment — we're drafting far more than we're playing, for a mix of practice, learning, and fun. This means it's semi-regular we'll look up a new commander for certain colours.

Searching for mono- or dual-colored commanders is fine with the colour identity search, using [`ci:r t:legendary t:creature`](http://magiccards.info/query?q=ci:r+t:legendary+t:creature) for monocolored red commanders, or the same legendary creature filter with [`ci:wum`](http://magiccards.info/query?q=ci:wum+t:legendary+t:creature) for white/blue commanders.

However, every search for three-coloured commanders and above also includes every two-colour commander that could be found therein. A search for Temur commanders with [`ci:gurm`](http://magiccards.info/query?q=ci:gurm+t%3Alegendary+t%3Acreature&v=card&s=cname) turns up all the green-blue-red commanders, but it also turns up all green-red, green-blue, and red-blue commanders, meaning I have to mentally sift those out each time I want to explore commander options. The exclusive (`!`) filter of [`ci!gurm`](http://magiccards.info/query?q=ci!gurm+t%3Alegendary+t%3Acreature&v=card&s=cname) has no noticeable difference.

**How can I perform an exclusive color identity match for commanders of three colours or more, in order to get a commander who has *those exact colours,* without also getting commanders that match only a subset of those colours?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you search `ci:gur` on magiccards.info, you are looking for cards that *match* that color identity, i.e. that are legal in a deck with whose commander has a GUR color identity, including artifacts. When you append the `m`, it appears to search for cards that have more than one of those colors in their color identity.

So, in that context, when you are looking for a GUR commander, you are really looking for a card that matches that color identity, but does not match any subset of that color identity.. You can express that using the negation syntax to filter out those sub-combinations, like `-ci:ru`. The final search is [`t:creature t:legendary ci:gur -ci:gu -ci:ur -ci:gr`](http://magiccards.info/query?q=t%3Acreature%20t%3Alegendary%20ci%3Agur%20-ci%3Agu%20-ci%3Aur%20-ci%3Agr&v=card&s=cname). This results in a total of six creatures that have that exact color identity.

---

I created a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/magiccardsinfo-commander/bgdhjjclbgkpddcelnamnomfmhgaamom) to help construct that search automatically. I also recently discovered [EDHREC](http://www.edhrec.com/), a site with similar search functionality.